# Delete extra . in filename on a OpenVMS system

Tags: filesystems, remove, openvms

I've downloaded, with ftp, a file which contains too many <kbd>.</kbd>s for a OpenVMS system.

```
swing-layout-1^.0.jar
```

How can I remove the extra dot?

Comment: What is the filename ?

Comment: swing-layout-1^.0.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it:

`set process/parse_style=extended`

Native OpenVMS uses the dots to delimit the file name, type and version numbers. The first dot in this case has '^' preceding it to indicate that it is just part of the name, is not the end of the name and start of the type (which is jar).

- Name: swing-layout-1.0
- Type: jar
- Version: (not specified)

The parse_style=extended allows this to work with a file from another realm where the dot has no special meaning to the file system.